# How to develop authentication of REST queries correctly when REST client is browser

Tags: rest, authentication, browser, request

I am at start of develoment of web-application. Application should be RESTful.
I am new to REST. And now I can't understand how user login/logout need to be done correctly to meet REST restrictions.

I spent good time to understand REST and already read many articles and answers on StackOverflow. Also I understand basic principle of "stateless" and it's benefits. So please no links on Wikipedia and basic sources about REST.

About task:
I have list of books in database on server. User who has login/password may come to site, enter login/password and view page with these books. So before to answer with list of books server need to be sure that user has rights to do it.

List of books will requested by AJAX call from browser.

I am going to make server to handle URL /books . When server receives GET request to this URL - it should
    1) authenticate this call;
    2) if OK - answer with list of books in JSON format.

As I understand so far - correct way of authentication for REST server is to authenticate each separate call. Client should use Secret Access Key and Access Key ID to encrypt query parameters. And server will check for Access Key ID, retrieve Secret Access Key (that is shared secret) and validate query in this way.

So server doesn't handle sessions because it violates "stateless" restriction of REST.
Only way how I see it could be done without sessions - use some Secret Access Key and Access Key ID to encrypt query parameters. This is how usual REST clients do. But there is a big difference between "normal" REST client and browser REST client.
Normal REST client (lets say it is standalone application or PHP-application on server) stores their Secret Access Key in some secure way. Nobody can see it. But JS application stores it right in code. And anybody can open this JS code and find this key.

So my question is:
How to organize authentication between browser (REST client) and server that handles REST API without exposing Secret Key to anybody who can open source code.

Or maybe I overestimate issue of storing of Secret Access Key in code?
I just see big difference with classical "stateful" application:
    If I am logged in to some site and out of computer at the moment - nobody can come to computer and find my password in any place in memory of browser.
    But with storing Secret Access Key in code it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Basic authentication which works with browser based application. But problem with it is that it will always throw a pop-up to the user. An alternative to it is that you use a custom login header to do the authentication of each REST request, for example

```
headers : { "Authorization" : "customAuth" }
```